# Redis on windows throwing error : READONLY You can't write against a read only slave., sPort: xxxxx , LastCommand:

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

I am getting this error on my production server, local server it is working fine.  It is a web application using Servicestack.redis.

I have installed Redis server as windows service but suddenly after 5 days it starts throwing this error "**READONLY You can't write against a read only slave., sPort: xxxxx, LastCommand**:"
where sPort is giving different value each time/request.

**I haven't configured master - slave**.

Not sure why this error comes up.
Anyone faces this scenario earlier?

Answer (score 0):

In my company we start using Memurai. Now the work is done faster and efficiently. I really enjoy this product